# If Composer cannot be installed on production server is it OK to track vendor folder in Git?

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

As I understand it, with any project that uses Composer, the correct way to deploy to production server is by not tracking the `vendor` folder in Git, but instead running Composer on the production server and letting it fetch all the necessary packages and populate the `vendor` folder for you. **Firstly, have I got that bit right?** *(This may sound like a stupid question but nobody has ever explicitly stated this to me)*

Secondly, my production server is a cheap shared hosting environment, not a shiny expensive AWS or Digital Ocean box, so I cannot install Composer in the production environment. As much as I'd like to do things the *ideal* way, I can't. So is the next best option to track the `vendor` folder in Git and deploy the packages that way. Then in the future, if I upgrade to a hosting package with more flexibility, I can stop tracking the `vendor` folder and start doing things the ideal way?

Comment: Responses : Yes. Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of how the vendor map is supposed to be used is correct.

For your second question, I would only choose your solution as a last resort; it's far from ideal. Your repository will need constantly updating with third-party changes.

In you case I would prefer to:

1. Install php, composer and git locally. This is possible in Windows, OSX and Linux.
2. Mirror your site locally, and perform the composer updates there.
3. Copy updates via FTP (or whatever you use) to your production site.

This keeps your repository compact and managable. You only ever need to commit your own changes to the repository.

If, at any point in the future, you can run git on the server, you can keep using the repository without having to clear out the entire vendor map.

Comment: Do you really trust a manual process of uploading via FTP over using Git?! That seems so backwards that I didn't suggest it in the original question.

Comment: keep in mind that your local development copy of you project might have some dev related packages installed that are needed for dev only and you don't want in your production copy! So at least have a local production copy (which is synchronized with your server), might be a good idea if you can't run composer on your server.

Comment: @MartinJoiner I don't know how far you intended to automate the process :-) . We used `rsync` for years to automate our deploys, and came to trust it completely. I didn't suggest `rsync` because I suspect your provider won't support it, and FTP is ubiquitous. I would rather mirror locally than track third-party in git.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how people usually use composer.

If you have shell access on this server, you can easily use composer. Just include composer.phar in repo, then you can run `php composer.phar install` on your shared server.

You can get latest composer from their website (https://getcomposer.org/download/).

If you don't have shell access, then you can put vendor in git, but I would rather copy vendor manually via FTP, than store this in git. 
I assume, that since you use git on your server side, that you have shell access, and that's not the case ;)

Comment: This should have been a comment as it doesn't answer the question(s).

Comment: @Veve I am not able to comment on posts, since I don't have 50 reputation. Thanks for helping getting that though 